# Symfony2 - How to implement partial / full templates for loading AJAX content in twig?

Tags: ajax, symfony, twig, template-inheritance

In my Symfony2/twig webapp I have a twig template, that only contains a `<div id="#container">...</div>`, no `<html></html>` wrapping. I use this for an ajax call where I embed this into my page layout. Let's call this layout `ajax_template.html.twig`.

```
<h1>Headline</h1>
{% block my_content %}
    <p>My content</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Now I have another template, that shall extend the `ajax_template.html.twig`. But this page is not called via ajax, but directly. So it shall also extend my `base_layout.html.twig`, where all the `<html></html>` wrapping is included. Should be something like:

```
# won't work because no multiple inheritance supported
{% extends 'MyBundle::base_layout.html.twig' %}
{% extends 'MyBundle:MyController:ajax_template.html.twig' %}

{% block my_content %}
    <p>My modified content</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Already tried a couple of methods, e.g. `include()` or `use()` in my twig templates. I also had a check, if the current path is an ajax call:

```
{% if '/ajax/' in path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) %}
    {% extends 'MyBundle::base_layout.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

But none of my approaches work. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Richard Miller](http://richardmiller.co.uk/) wrote a nice article that shows a good way to implement partial templates for AJAX-use.

The article is called "**[Symfony2: Ajax and Full Page Templates](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2013/02/18/symfony2-ajax-and-full-page-templates/#comment-69062)**".

Lateron he published a second - more detailed - article that additionally covers [my suggestions](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2013/02/27/symfony2-more-twig-ajax-templates/#comment-80343) called "**[More on AJAX templates](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2013/02/27/symfony2-more-twig-ajax-templates/)**".

These two articles (especially the second one) provide detailed implementation examples of what you're trying to do here.

---

Basically the trick is to determine the template to extend from a variable as you can't wrap ...

```
{% extends '..' %}
```

... with a surrounding `{% if %}`-statement.

---

**working example**

```
{% set template = 'MyBundle::base_layout.html.twig' %}

{% if '/ajax/' in path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) %}
    {% set template = 'MyBundle:MyController:ajax_template.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}

{% extends template %}
```

Please note that a solution involving a twig extension (as described in the above mentioned articles) is re-usable and generally a better practice.

Comment: There is no need to extend both, they can extend each other linearly ... either the partial template gets included into the main template ... or the partial template has empty wrapping blocks that the main template fills. got me?

Comment: Not really. Could you give a simple example with three twig files (1. base_template, 2. template, 3. ajax_partial; where ajax_template has not the base_template wrapping)?

Comment: I mean: Where goes your working example, into the base_layout, into the template or into the ajax_template?

Comment: The example code should be put into the template that shall extend either the full or the partial base-template based on wether the incoming request was an ajax-request.

Comment: Ah okay, now I get. I need to do a little rework on my code to design it like this but this'll help me. Thanks a lot!